# How to insert hyperlinks inside an accordion?

Tags: html, hyperlink, angular-material, material-design, accordion

I need to insert a bunch of blue hyperlinks inside an accordion. So when we click the title, the expansion area that appears would contain a couple lines that call some function.

I've attempted to follow the example on the Angular Material website:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/ybovddobxlj?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

I've modified expansion-overview-example.html to the following:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            ALL FILES
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div> <!-- To put them on separate lines -->
        <mat-form-field>
            <label title="File 1" onclick="openFile1()"></label> <!-- THIS LINE BREAKS THE PAGE. HELP? -->
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div> <!-- To put them on separate lines -->
      <mat-form-field>
            <label title="File 2" onclick="openFile2()"></label> <!-- THIS LINE BREAKS THE PAGE. HELP? -->
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove the `mat-form-field`, it is not required if you just want a simple link in the accordion (this is actually what breaks your code).

Just add a simple `p` tag with a `(click)` event handler (it is not `onclick` in Angular). This should do the trick:

```
<div>
  <p (click)="openFile1()">File 1</p>
</div>
```

If you want to use `label` instead, use it like this:

```
<div>
  <label (click)="openFile2()">File 2</label> 
</div>
```

It should have a value, otherwise it is not visible and you can't click it.

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-c7wx9k?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
>   is a stackblitz with your sample code edited to make it work.

Comment: Wow. You made it seem super easy. Thank you very much for your help.